# startsWith with solr and whitespaces

Tags: solr

How do I query for a field that starts with a specific sentence ?
For example I want to search for : "Oliver Hard*"

I expect exact one match for "Oliver Hardy". I have only one entry that starts with "Oliver Hardy".

following I tried, which didn't work:

`"q":actorsName:Oliver Hard*` -> brings me all Olivers and some fuzzy logic

`"q":actorsName:"Oliver Hard*`" -> the same

How to query with startsWith and whitespaces in Solr ?

Comment: What's the type of the field `actorsName`? Any match will have to happen on a token level, so if the field is analyzed and tokenized, it'll usually be split into separate tokens (and your query means `actorsName:Oliver <default search field>:Hard*`). To solve that issue, index the content to a `string` field which keeps everything as a single token, then use `actorName:Oliver\ Hard*` to query it. Check if that works (and if you need the field tokenized, index content into two fields by using `copyField`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the String as field type for your field.

String as field type will not tokenize the word and keep as it is which will help you to achieve the exact match.

> String stores a word/sentence as an exact string without performing
> tokenization etc. Commonly useful for storing exact matches, e.g, for
> facetting. Text typically performs tokenization, and secondary
> processing (such as lower-casing etc.)

Another option which will help you in case if you want to achieve the lowercase search as well.

```
<fieldType name="forExactMatch" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
             input string is preserved as a single token
          -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
             when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
          -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```